# Add image into a tooltip

Tags: wpf, image, tooltip, textblock

I have some TextBlocks with tooltips and I'd like to add an image into the tooltips (that means, I'd like to have tooltips with text and images).

Does anybody knows how could I do that in a simple way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is one way to approach it:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="images/Item 2.gif" />
            <TextBlock>My tooltip text</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
     </TextBlock.ToolTip>

    Here is my text.
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<TextBlock ToolTip="Content"/>
```

You can do:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
    <!--insert everything you want here-->
        <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: To add additional elements to the tooltip, the children of TextBlock.ToolTip must be wrapped in a container of sorts (etc Grid, StackPanel, etc)

Comment: I didnt know that, i always thought the template was using a plain ContentPresenter. I got some reflecting to do i t seems.